# Ckeckbox marked angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have an HTML structure mounted within a ng-repeat with ckeckboxes horizontally and vertically is a multidimensional array . When I click on one, I have to save to the database. So far so good , the problem being to bring these checkbox marked because the method that I bring the results , the model of the array of myself as undefined. Follow the link codes :

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/8eepu0o8/`
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for, and the fiddle you provided can't properly reproduce your issue since it depends on hitting your backend API. Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies here:

> the model of the array of myself as undefined

Investigate why that's undefined (e.g. F12 your code, put debugger, write to  console) - you won't get anything from model by binding to an undefined object.